# Is $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{p_{n}^{2}+1}{p_{n}^{2}-1} = 2.5$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, infinite-product

In this formula, $p_n$ represents the nth prime

$$
\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{p_{n}^{2}+1}{p_{n}^{2}-1} = 2.5
$$

I don't know if this is true or just a coincidence but if someone can help me figure it out that would be much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Peruse [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) about how to ask a good question on this site. In particular, you'll be more likely to get good answer(s) if you explain what you know about this question, where it arises, and why you think the identity might be true. What have you tried? Does it mimic some other calculation that you're familiar with? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: *Mathematica* says "yes... it is true."

Comment: I just ran a calculation in Python: for all primes less powers of $10$, here's the data: 
$$
\begin{array}{r|l} 
    10 & 2.350983796296297 \\
   100 & 2.490923358181373 \\
  1000 & 2.499365131666407 \\
 10000 & 2.499950921976173 \\
100000 & 2.499995988758179 
\end{array}
$$